# "...made us be happy" or "...made us happy"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Which of these sentences is correct and more common?

> 1. The show made us be happy.
> 2. The show made us happy.

To me both are correct with a little difference in meaning!

Comment: Good question +1

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, the show forced you to be happy, whereas in the second one you got happy by the simple presence of the show.
More generally:

> To **make/have** someone **do** something

Means to force someone to do something, through persuasive means or even by force.

For instance:

> My mother made me wash the dishes

Means that, through authority, your mom forced you to do something.
You'll understand that having the show forcing you to do things sounds a little ... bizarre !

Comment: Isn't the first one incorrect grammatically?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is per se, but I can't think of any case where it would make sense. I'm not that sure though and can't find any documentation on that, so I won't guarantee you 100%.

Comment: I agree that the first is grammatically correct, but remember @franky that something can be both grammatically correct *and* nonsensical.

Comment: P.S. MadWard, I agree with you that being forced to be happy is an odd concept, but that is more or less what that sentence means. The best I can do to put that into a context where it kind of makes sense is something like "After a rough day at work and an hour stuck in traffic I was determined to be miserable, but the show was so good it *made* me be happy." (If I were speaking aloud I'd put extra emphasis on "made". Except that in practice I'd find another way to express that sentiment.)